# Google Maps API extract directions

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions

I am a EE major. My project is to get directions from Google Map API to a particular coordinate and send it to my micro-controller through GSM module. I have already set up UDP, web and database servers so I have got the communication up and running, what I can't figure out is a way to extract the directions from the Google maps API in text.

I have seen the API examples. It only displays the directions on the website. I wanted to ask that how would I extract the directions (textual form) from the API (if it's at all possible)? Would it be possible to get turn by turn navigation if we are equipped with a gps?

As am a electrical engineer I don't have a lot to experience with web servers etc. Also please explain the flow of data from JavaScript to our udp/tcp client connected to micro-controller.

Also explain the project feasibility and difficulty level. It would be helpful if someone posted a sample or pseudo code which can help me understand the access to Google directions better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to iterate over `route->legs->steps`

each step has a property `instructions` which contains the desired data.

Note: When you request the [Directions-Webservice](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) the property is called `html_instructions`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But you didn't answer the second part of my question regarding the real time navigation using gps

Comment: There is no need to answer it, because it's not allowed: [no real time navigation or route guidance](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?#section_10_2)